# Bitnami Lamp stack subdomain

Tags: apache2, subdomain, lamp, bitnami

I purchased a bitnami lamp stack Server from aws and create a laravel Project. The page is reachable and works so far. Now I would like to create a subdomain.
I tried following:

Inside here:

> /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf

I changed following:

```
# Bitnami applications installed in a prefix URL
#Include "/opt/bitnami/frameworks/zendframework/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
                    Include "/opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
                    #Include "/opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
                    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

to following:

```
# Bitnami applications installed in a prefix URL
#Include "/opt/bitnami/frameworks/zendframework/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
                    Include "/opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
                    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

And finally made a Server Restart:

> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

But the subdomain / page does not Show up, the main page still works.
Is there any step which I missed?

Comment: Hey Jaan, I am currently having the same issue, have you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: @HeWang didnt find a solution yet I was hoping that Jota Martos  could provide something

Comment: I've been searching for solution as well, based on what I've found, I reckon you should move this line `Include "/opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"` from `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf`

Comment: @HeWang did that work for you? Thus where do you put all your subdomains the Project Folders and the configuration for them?

Comment: That's not working for me because I am trying to have two WordPress sites on one Lightsail instance. I asked my question in Bitnami forum and Jota suggested me to use WordPress Multisite feature, I haven't looked into that yet. I reckon that you can post your question in that forum as well, Jota replied to me pretty quickly there.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here.

You are including the "/opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf" file inside the bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file that is included in the default Virtual Host of Apache, that's why you can't access the application in the subdomain. Instead of adding this line

`Include "/opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"`

in the bitnami-apps-prefix.conf, you will need to include it in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` one. This way, you will define a the new Virtual Host after restarting Apache.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late request, I got confuse, you tell me to remove `"/opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"` line inside the `bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` which has following Location: `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami` and put it inside `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` which is basically the same Location? Am I missing something, because that would be like remove and replacing the line.

Comment: Could you set me an example how how to set subdomain using bitnami currently my Project is inside `/opt/bitnami/Frameworks/laravel` and I would like to create subdomains in a clear way